# There seems to be a redirect bug

Tags: pagespeed-insights

If we enter the domain name manually like "xyz.com" then it automatically picks "HTTP" instead of "https' on google page speed insight.

This seems to be a bug because this behavior is across all sites.

And then google page speed insights show lower score thanks to the HTTP version.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug.

When you enter a domain name without **http or https** in your URL bar in your browser it will try **http** first.

This carries with it a performance hit that should be considered as part of any speed testing.

Depending on how you do your redirects this can be anywhere from 10ms to 100ms and so needs to be considered.

Where the problem lies is that it should actually strip https first, as if you enter https instead of http it will not take the redirect into account on your final score.

**Always** enter your domain without http or https for the most accurate picture of your site performance.

The test for 'too many redirects' does not care what you enter, the above only affects the speed test results.

Your site should not be able to run on HTTP (just thought I would say that for clarity) and should always redirect to HTTPS, hence why this is important.

Comment: Udnerstood, but isn't google cut more points for having HTTP? When I test with https it gives 90+ score without https it gives low score

Comment: Google does cut points if you don't redirect `http` to `https`,  the low score however is likely that your redirects are not quite right, care to share your URL and I will see if I can see anything else.